# Popping View Controller when not using a Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have searched around and all cases of using the pop to return to a previous view controller seem to be based around using a navigation controller, I am using a tab bar controller and have no real need to the navigation controller and so havent implemented it.

I load this detailed view controller via a segue based on rowindex selected in a list controller and just need to close it when they are done reading with a close button.

Is there still a method that can be used to pop a view controller without it all being housed in a navigation controllers unnecessarily?

Comment: A `pop` only makes sense if the controller was presented with a `push`. It sounds like you're looking for an unwind segue to dismiss your modal detail view controller or otherwise reverse whatever segue you used to present it.

Comment: thanks i wasn't aware of this method so ill have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a Storyboard and use an Unwind Segue to go back to the prev. View? Take a look at this [Unwind Segue](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/), hope will help you.